# Bulk product import error SKU not defined

Tags: magento2, product, magento-1, import

I have a product sheet with some 200 odd products. When I am trying to import these product I get an error saying "Skipping import row, required field SKU not defined", even  though all the SKUs are present. It happens with most of the products but some products do get imported. Don't understand the difference. My SKUs are four digit numbers only in general excel formate. can someone pls tell me what i am doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me recently and I found that it was because the quote + comma requirement for the csv was incorrect.
If you make sure that everything in the spreadsheet is properly quoted (blank fields don't matter i think) and double check that everything is comma seperated.

Tip: just take the first line and keep adding one line at a time until an import produces the error and you should see straight away which line causes the first error. 90% chance this line won't be quoted properly.

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend NEVER using Excel for Magento imports. Whenever you export an excel file to .CSV it always adds hidden characters and you'll always get import errors like "Duplicate Columns" and such. I always use Google Docs Spreadsheet. Just hit export>CSV and you'll see that you get a lot smoother and error-less imports!

Comment: This.

Use google sheets, not excel.

Excel not only turns all your LF into CRLF, but also adds so much more junk space to your file. Magento has a 2MB file size import limit so it makes a big difference. With google sheets I can get 5k-8k products per import. With excel, the number is like a 1k, but not even because you can't even upload the excel-generated CSV file anyway

Answer (score 1):

This can be due to the format that excel saves your CSV in.  Can you open the file in notepad and check the format of your CSV?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the way you asked your question, did you name the column SKU with all caps? It needs to be sku with all lower case

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was caused by Excel saving with the delimiter `;` semikolon instead of comma `,` but comma was selected in the import profile.

I changed it to `;` in the dataflow import profile and now it works !